# wxPython - DropSource.SetData() workes with string but not with list

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I want to drag and drop a list item to another list. Both lists got two columns. I got it working with drag and dropping the value from the first column to the other list. But drag and drop bot values from column 0 and 1 to the other list wont work.

How do i use DropSource.SetData()  with a list?

Here is the part of my Code:

```
def OnDragInit(self, event):
    #text = self.lst1.GetItemText(event.GetIndex(),0)   
    #tobj = wx.TextDataObject(text) #Doesnt work with a list
    # With the above two lines everything is working fine!
    # Error here
    text = []
    text.append(self.lst1.GetItemText(event.GetIndex(),0))
    text.append(self.lst1.GetItemText(event.GetIndex(),1))

    src = wx.DropSource(self.lst1)
    src.SetData(text)

    src.DoDragDrop(True)
    self.lst1.DeleteItem(event.GetIndex())
```

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: DropSource.SetData(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using a `wx.TextDropTarget` with a `wx.TextDataObject` and what you are passing is clearly a `list`.
You will need to create custom data object, then serialise the `list` on drag and de-serialise it on drop.

To serialise/de-serialise the list you can use `pickle` or `marshal` and I'm led to believe that you could use `json` as well but I didn't really look into that.

The coding for a list `drag & drop` can get quite complicated, so I've put this code together for you to visualise how you might implement it.

The code is commented, so hopefully you will be able to see what is what.
It is slightly more complicated than it has to be, as I have allowed for dragging and dropping from/to lists with an unequal number of columns.
Also note, that you can drag and drop onto the same list.

```
import wx
import pickle
#import marshal

class MyTarget(wx.PyDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, object):
        wx.DropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.object = object
        # specify the type of data to accept
        self.data = wx.CustomDataObject("ListCtrlItems")
        self.SetDataObject(self.data)

    # Called when OnDrop returns True.
    def OnData(self, x, y, opt):
        # Find insertion point in the target.
        index, flags = self.object.HitTest((x, y))

        if self.GetData():
            # unpickle data
            listdata = self.data.GetData()
            dropped_list = pickle.loads(listdata)
            #dropped_list = marshal.loads(listdata)

        if index == -1: # if not inserting, set index to the end of the listctrl
            index = self.object.GetItemCount()

        #Insert at drop point
        for row in dropped_list:
            self.object.InsertItem(index, row[0]) #Insert item
            cols = self.object.GetColumnCount()
            for pos in range(1,cols):
                try:
                    self.object.SetItem(index, pos, row[pos]) #Add extra columns data
                except Exception as e: # run out of columns in target
                    pass
            index +=1
        return True

class Mywin(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title,size= (600,-1))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.listCtrl1 = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_HRULES)
        self.listCtrl1.InsertColumn(0, "Item0")
        self.listCtrl1.SetColumnWidth(0,100)
        self.listCtrl1.InsertColumn(1, "Item1")
        self.listCtrl1.SetColumnWidth(1,100)
        self.listCtrl2 = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES|wx.LC_HRULES)
        self.listCtrl2.InsertColumn(0, "Item0")
        self.listCtrl2.SetColumnWidth(0,100)
        self.listCtrl2.InsertColumn(1, "Item1")
        self.listCtrl2.SetColumnWidth(0,100)
        self.listCtrl2.InsertColumn(2, "Item2")
        self.delete = wx.CheckBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Delete on move")
        self.delete.SetToolTip("Delete original item when dragged & dropped")
        self.delete.SetValue(True)

        #load sample data
        data = [["abc",1],["def",2],["ghi",3]]
        for i in data:
            self.listCtrl1.Append((i))

        data = [["ABC",1,"first"],["DEF",2,"second"],["GHI",3,"third"]]
        for i in data:
            self.listCtrl2.Append((i))

        #Target Left
        tl = MyTarget(self.listCtrl1)
        self.listCtrl1.SetDropTarget(tl)

        #Target Right
        tr = MyTarget(self.listCtrl2)
        self.listCtrl2.SetDropTarget(tr)

        self.listCtrl1.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnDrag)
        self.listCtrl2.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnDrag)

        box.Add(self.listCtrl1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.listCtrl2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.delete, 0, wx.ALIGN_TOP)
        panel.SetSizer(box)
        panel.Fit()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnDrag(self, event):
        #create a data object for drag-and-drop
        object = event.GetEventObject() # listCtrl1 or listCtrl2
        list_data = []
        idx = -1
        while True: # find all the selected items and put them in a list
            idx = object.GetNextSelected(idx)
            if idx == -1:
                break
            item_data = []
            for item in range(object.GetColumnCount()): # get data from all columns
                item_data.append(object.GetItem(idx, item).GetText())
            list_data.append(item_data)

        # Pickle the items list.
        pickle_data = pickle.dumps(list_data)
        #pickle_data = marshal.dumps(list_data)
        # create custom data object
        cdataobj = wx.CustomDataObject("ListCtrlItems")
        cdataobj.SetData(pickle_data)
        # Now make a data object for the item list.
        data = wx.DataObjectComposite()
        data.Add(cdataobj)

        # Create drop source and begin drag-and-drop.
        dropSource = wx.DropSource(object)
        dropSource.SetData(data)
        result = dropSource.DoDragDrop(True)

        # delete dropped items from source list
        if self.delete.GetValue(): # Is delete checkbox ticked
            if result == wx.DragCopy: # Was the drag and drop successful
                while True:
                    #For this small sample always start at the beginning (-1)
                    idx = object.GetNextSelected(-1)
                    if idx == -1: #No more selected items
                        break
                    object.DeleteItem(idx)

demo = wx.App()
Mywin(None,'Drag & Drop ListCtrl Demo')
demo.MainLoop()
```

In answer to your comment about the result coming back from the `DoDragDrop`:

> The DragResult enumeration provides the following values:
>
> Description   Value
> DragError Error prevented the D&D operation from completing.
> DragNone  Drag target didn’t accept the data.
> DragCopy  The data was successfully copied.
> DragMove  The data was successfully moved (MSW only).
> DragLink  Operation is a drag-link.
> DragCancel    The operation was cancelled by user (not an error).
>
> DoDragDrop(self, flags=Drag_CopyOnly) Starts the drag-and-drop
> operation which will terminate when the user releases the mouse.
>
> Call this in response to a mouse button press, for example.
>
> Parameters:   flags (int) – If wx.Drag_AllowMove is included in the
> flags, data may be moved and not only copied as is the case for the
> default wx.Drag_CopyOnly . If wx.Drag_DefaultMove is specified (which
> includes the previous flag), moving is not only possible but becomes
> the default operation. Return type:   wx.DragResult Returns:  The
> operation requested by the user, may be wx.DragCopy , wx.DragMove ,
> wx.DragLink , wx.DragCancel or wx.DragNone if an error occurred.

[image: Initial View]

[image: Drag 2 items from left panel to right panel (inserting)]

[image: Drag 2 items from right panel to left panel (appending)]

Comment: Thank you very much! The comments helped me alot to get behind everything.

Comment: The only Thing in do not understand is: why does result == wx.DragCopy doesnt work. wx.DragCopy Returns "2" if i print it. result is 1 for true.

Comment: @mk1337 See my amended answer. `True` (1) was sent as a flag, the `result` returning from the routine is an entirely different thing. Try dropping a list item somewhere other than one of the 2 panels, depending on where you drop it, you should get a result of either 1 or 5 i.e. DragNone or DragCancel

Comment: I get what you are saying and i also understand what wx.DragCopy does. But also if i drag and drop on anything else except the 2 Panels it Returns "2". I tested it with `print(wx.DragCopy)`